# Button in ASP, called in C# file via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have a asp.net page where it has the following properties

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" CssClass="Button" Text="< Back to Home" /></td>
```

And in the C# code file I am doing something like this

```
btnBack.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:history.go(-1);return false");
```

The problem is it is not always returning me to the Home page but some other page..

Is there anyway I can add in this function the page where I want to navigate for instance (and I know its wrong but please see what i want to achieve)

```
    btnBack.Attributes.Add("onclick", "~/Home.aspx");
```

Something like that

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you aren't always getting the behavior of moving back to the home page is because `history.go(-1)` just tells the browser to navigate back to the previous page that was loaded. It may not always be the home page.

A simple solution from javascript is to change the location property which will trigger the broswer to load the URL supplied

```
btnBack.OnClientClick = "window.location='http://www.google.com'";
```

The OnClientClick will attach the javascript string to the onclick event in html markup for you. This is easier and cleaner IMO than something like 
`btnBack.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.location=~/Home.aspx"`

Answer (score 0):

```
btnBack.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='http://google.com'");
```

Comment: `location` is an object; you are looking for `location.href`, which is a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnBack.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:window.location.reload('Home.aspx');return false;")
```

Comment: Please do **not** add `javascript:` to event attributes.